# A.e. inequality from integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Suppose that for some measurable real-valued function $f$,
$$\int_A fdm \leq C,$$
where $m$ is a probability measure, for all Borel $A$, with $C$ being a constant not depending on the sets $A$. Does this imply that $f\leq C$ $m$-a.e.?

A similar results states that if $\int_A fdm = \int_A gdm,$ then $f= g$ $m$-a.e. (e.g. [Is $f=g$ almost everywhere if their integrals over any subset are the same?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3489956/is-f-g-almost-everywhere-if-their-integrals-over-any-subset-are-the-same)), but I believe one cannot simply extend this result to this problem. I made an attempt by considering sets like $A_n = \{x:f(x) - 1/n \leq C\}$, so that one wants to show that $m(\cup A_n)=1$, but I wasn't able to going forward meaningfully.

Also, what if e.g. $m$ has a density, $f$ is continuous or anything? Is this result true at least in some cases? Any book that might contain this sort of results? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for non-negative $f,$ your hypothesis boils down to $\int fdm\le C.$

So: no, it is too weak to imply $f\le C$ a.e., even for the simplest measured space, $m(\{0\})=m(\{1\})=\frac12$: take $f(0)=3,f(1)=1,C=2.$

And you can easily transform this counterexample to have a density for $m$ and continuity for $f.$

The correct [hypothesis to get $f\le C$ a.e. is $\int_Afd m\le Cm(A)$ for all  measurable $A.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2998774)

Answer (score 1):

It does not. Consider $ f(x) = 1_{(1/2,1)}(x)\cdot 10$ - then, $ \int f(x) dx \leq 5$ for all Borel sets.